# implicit Scala bug or is it me?

Tags: scala

Cutting right to the chase

"Convert" int to String

```
 implicit def int2string(i: Int): String = {
    "foo"
  }
```

Method that takes a String and prints

```
def printString(i: String) = print(i)
```

Calling printString with an Int argument

```
printString(_:Int)
```

Shouldn't that display "foo"? However `printString(i:String)` never gets called.

`printString(1)` prints "foo"

Is there a problem here or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because what `printString(_:Int)` actually what it does is to turn that expression in a function that takes a Int and probably is never invoked... See:

```
scala> implicit def int2string(i: Int): String = "foo"
int2string: (i: Int)String

scala> def printString(i: String) = print(i)
printString: (i: String)Unit
```

No syntax error here mean it is working. As an illustration:

```
scala> printString(_:Int)       // Function from Int to Unit 
res0: Int => Unit = <function1>
```

The compiler turns the outer expression into `{ x:Int => printString(x) }`, and then applies the implicit conversion since the implicit is in scope, so the outcome is `{ x:Int => printString(int2string(x)) }`.

A non-working one, since there is no conversion from Object to String:

```
scala> printString(_:Object)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.Object
 required: String
              printString(_:Object)
```

Now to actually see the printing we need to invoke it:

```
scala> val foo = printString(_:Int)
foo: Int => Unit = <function1>

scala> foo(5)
foo
```

Comment: yes it does. But again def printString get a String argument and not an (Int) => String .
implicit int2String allows scala to compile yet the is no printString(i:Int =>String) to call. Isn't that weird behavior?

Comment: No, not really. You are missing the point here. I will try to improve the explanation here.

Comment: It's exactly what implicit conversion using for, you have an variable of type Int, but you want it convert to String when you give it to a function. So you define a `implicit def` that let Scala do all this work for you. Pretty reasonable for me.

Comment: ok "actually does it is to turn that expression" seems that i couldn't see that before. thank you for the help on this

Comment: Added another paragraph under the first `printString(_:Int)`

Answer (score 1):

The following Scala REPL pretty much tells the whole story, its never get called is because `printString(_:Int)` is not a function call. You are creating a new function.

If you passed in the int directly, the everything is OK.

```
scala>  implicit def int2string(i: Int): String = {
     |     "foo"
     |   }
int2string: (i: Int)String

scala> def printString(i: String) = print(i)
printString: (i: String)Unit

scala> val x = printString(_:Int)
x: Int => Unit = <function1>

scala> x(10)
foo

// This works because you have implicit def, 
// and this will be printString(int2string(10)) 
// when your argument is a Int.
scala> printString(10) 
foo
scala>
```